# Full size of an Android View being clipped by its parent

Tags: android, layout, view, size, android-linearlayout

Please take a look at this xml layout.

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/dataTableContainer"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:clipChildren="true">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/dataTable"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:orientation="vertical"/>  

    </LinearLayout>
```

At runtime the "dataTable" element is populated with children that are wider than what the "dataTableContainer" can display. However, as I inspect in eclipse the mMeasuredWidth of the two elements (or even the return value of getWidth()), they turn out to be exactly the same. This shouldn't be the case. My understanding is that the children of "dataTable" should push it to assume their own width given its "wrap_content" setting. Conversely, "dataTableContainer" should be smaller than that, given its "fill_parent" setting which is constrained by the screen size.

I've also tried with "clipChildren" set to false, just in case the width gets clipped by the container but the result remain the same: both table and container have the same width.

Can anybody explain what's going on?

To give you some context, what I'm trying to do is to gather the sizes of these elements to determine how much of the "dataTable" element lies -outside- of the container and therefore unseen. This in turn is needed to limit how far the user can drag the table element. ScrollView elements limit the motion natively, but as I'm using a LinearLayout I need to replicate that limiting functionality.

Comment: The inner `LinearLayout` can't be any larger than the outer one, so it seems reasonable that the widths would be equal. Do you really need the root element to be a `LinearLayout`? Could you wrap `dataTableContainer` in a `ScrollView`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @acj. I don't think it's so safe to assume that the inner element can't be larger than the outer one. Of course visually it can't, but internally I would have thought the rendering engine knows (and stores somewhere) that the inner element would like to be larger but is clipped by the outer element. I would therefore expect a discrepancy between the measured width and the value returned by getWidth().

Comment: To answer your question @acj, I cannot use ScrollView because I'm trying to create a simple 2D ScrollView, one that scrolls both horizontally and vertically. I have seen solutions for this but they seem to be a bit overkill for what I need to do. Dragging the inner element already work, but I don't know how to limit its motion so that it doesn't get out of the screen!

Comment: The [documentation for View drawing](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html) mentions that "[a] View's measured width and measured height values must respect the constraints imposed by the View's parents". The desired width/height for the Views seem to be discarded after the measure pass. Aside from populating `dataTable`, are you doing anything programmatically to change the inner layout's size or behavior?

Comment: Yes, I had read that paragraph from the docs and I find it a bit unclear, in the context of the fact that in some cases it is the parent to impose a size on the children and in some cases it seems to be the child to decide its own size. But it seems I have found what I needed and that my blind reliance on eclipse's inspecting tools was the problem. See my own answer on the issue.

Comment: My understanding is that the parent View imposes measurement constraints on its children unless you specify otherwise, which is precisely what your approach does. I think Eclipse was tracking the measurement variables from the native measurement pass. Glad to hear that you found a workable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that I was too trusting of Eclipse. While debugging using a breakpoint to inspect the state of the app and the values of many available variables, I relied on a list of variables provided by eclipse which included mMeasuredWidth/mMeasuredHeight. Notice that these are not variables from my source code. Eclipse somehow found them by itself, inspecting the objects for me. I therefore assumed that somehow they indeed represented -the- measured width/height. My assumption was wrong however, if only because a view can be measured in different ways (i.e. using MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED or MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) and eclipse can't know which measure I needed.

I therefore triggered the measuring I needed by adding to my code:

```
int measureSpecParams = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
dataTableView.measure(measureSpecParams, measureSpecParams);
int measuredWidth = dataTableView.getMeasuredWidth();
int measuredHeight = dataTableView.getMeasuredHeight();
```

This did give me the view sizes I was after, namely how big the "dataTable" view would be if the parent view nor the screen limited it.